# Fill a div only with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to fill differents divs with four colours, using only javascript (with a HTML structure off course), here's the code :

HTML

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="carre1" class="carre">1</div>
    <div id="carre2" class="carre">2</div>
    <div id="carre3" class="carre">3</div>
    <div id="carre4" class="carre">4</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var colors = {
    count: 4,
    tab : ["red","orange","yellow","green"]}
    ;
```

Let's say I want to make the div "carre1" red, how do I do that ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You want to animate the colors?

Comment: There are many ways you could do that. It's hard to know the right way without knowing more about how you want this to work.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your comments. No animation needed, and it was just a js alternative to the css, for training myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  for (var i = 0; i < colors.tab.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById("carre" + (i + 1)).style.backgroundColor= colors.tab[i];
```

Comment: Almost, should be `colors.tab`, but close enough.. [fiddle I just made](http://jsfiddle.net/tbCBG/).

Comment: I forgot to say I want the background to fill, not the text. Replacing "color" by "background" in your code works just fine, thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

In short:

```
for (var i=1; i<=colors['count']; i++) {
    document.getElementById("carre" + i).style.backgroundColor = colors['tab'][i-1];
}
```

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AdmkT/).

Also works with colors.tab and colors.count as in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AdmkT/1/).

Answer (score 0):

This is how you fill div's with colors in order they are stored in array:

```
carre = document.getElementsByClassName('carre');
for(i=0;i<colors.count;i++){
     carre[i].style.backgroundColor = colors.tab[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById("carre1").style.backgroundColor=colors.tab[0];`